# Parse List<List<String>> to List<DateTime> in dart/flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have response from server:

```
[
    [
        "2014",
        "01",
        "01"
    ],
    [
        "2015",
        "01",
        "01"
    ],
    [
        "2016",
        "01",
        "01"
    ]
]
```

I want to convert them to List. 
This is what I create:

```
final response = await _dio.get(
    "api/v1/calendar/holidays");
List<dynamic> list = response.data;
List<String> calendarList = List();
var dateList =
list.map((i) => ((a) => calendarList.add(a.toString()))).toList();

return calendarList;
```

but this returns me list of strings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = response.data
  .map((e) => DateTime.parse('${e[0]}-${e[1]}-${e[2]}'))
  .toList();
```

Comment: I get error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DateTime>'

Comment: I don't really understand why you get this error. Just replace `List<DateTime>` with `var` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If `response.data` is the list you posted in your question this should work.

```
var dateList = response.data[0].map((l) => DateTime(l[0], l[1], l]2])).toList()
```

You might need

```
var dateList = jsonDecode(response.data)[0].map((l) => DateTime(l[0], l[1], l]2])).toList()
```

depending on what format `response.data` actually is.

Comment: I get error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'